# Android: Get integer value of images in SD storage?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-bitmap

I'm looking to add images from my SD card storage into an Interger array list.

At the moment I can display images from my drawable folder because they are (somehow) in int format, for example: Log.d("MyTag", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)); currently returns me 2131230825.

I can access my SD card images in a way to return me: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.hangr.hangr/files/Pictures/Hangr_20181119__153130.jpg (String format). And I can also make bitmaps out of them with "Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(i));" (Bitmap format).

Any idea on how I can pass these string/bitmap forms into an int object?

```
package com.myapp.myapp;
imports ...
public class test extends Activity {

    public ArrayList<Integer> mThumbIds = new ArrayList<>();

    File[] listFile;
    ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();// list of file paths
    ArrayList<Bitmap> myBitmapArrayList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();// list of bitmaps

    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        getFromSdcard();

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        // Test: adding drawable items to my interger list
        mThumbIds.add(R.drawable.logo);   
    }

    //************** important function that calls from my SD card
    public void getFromSdcard(){
        File file = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listFile = file.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++)
            {
                f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(i));
                fml.add(myBitmap);
            }
        }
        //************** TESTING THE VALUE OF MY VARIABLES
        Log.d("MyTag", "File file " + file); ///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/Pictures
        Log.d("MyTag", "File length " + file.isDirectory()); //true
        Log.d("MyTag", "First element in f: " + f.get(0)); ///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/Pictures/20181119__153130.jpg

        Log.d("MyTag", "All the Bitmaps? " + myBitmapArrayList); //returns huge list of bitmaps, i.e. android.graphics.Bitmap@39bd71a
        Log.d("MyTag", "Drawables? " +  (R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)); //returns me 2131230825

    }



    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //************** code to zoom in on images, from https://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-gridview-zoom-images-animation-tutorial/


    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup                 parent) {

            final ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds.get(position));
           // imageView.setImageListener(bottoms_Listener);
            imageView.setTag(mThumbIds.get(position));
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    int id = (Integer) arg0.getTag();
                    zoomImageFromThumb(arg0, id);
                }
            });

            return imageView;
        }

        private void zoomImageFromThumb...


}
```

Before you get mad at me for not "trying", I have. The hardest part was pulling from the device storage and accessing the photos in there. I just dont get why drawable images are ints and why there's no seemingly straightforward way I can turn my images into ints for similar use.

Comment: `R.whatever` are classes holding integer references to the resources of your application. Android then uses those references to load the actual images. Images on internal storage on the SD card aren't resources, and have no integer references.

Comment: @TheWanderer Ahhh ok, guess that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't get their integer references, because they don't have any.

`R.whatever` (`R.drawable`, `R.string`, `R.xml`, etc) are classes generated by Android Studio that hold integer fields whose names correspond to your resources. When you use something like `getDrawable()`, Android uses the integer you passed to find the corresponding resource and load it as an image. This is all done because the resources are compiled and stored in the APK itself, and aren't accessible with paths.

However, images on internal storage or your SD card aren't resources. They have directly accessible paths, and aren't inside any APKs. Android doesn't give them integers IDs because they don't need them, and it's just not how it works.

To get images from storage, you need to use paths.